# Graph not getting displayed on html template django

Tags: python, django

So I am using Bokeh to plot graph on the page. Yet it shows four dots (' .... ') where it is supposed to plot the graph.
Below is my python file which is supposed to plot the graph.

```
from django.shortcuts import render , render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django import forms
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm
from django.urls import reverse
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show 
from bokeh.embed import components



def index(request):
    ### graph plotting stuff ###
    x= [1,3,5,7,9,11,13]
    y= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    title = 'y = f(x)'

    plot = figure(title= title , 
        x_axis_label= 'X-Axis', 
        y_axis_label= 'Y-Axis', 
        plot_width =400,
        plot_height =400)

    plot.line(x, y, legend= 'f(x)', line_width = 2)
    #Store components 

    script, div = components(plot)
    print("@#$!@")
    print(script)
    print("@#$!@")
    print(div)
    # return render(request, 'visit/index.html', context=None)
    return render(request, 'visit/index.html', {'script' : script , 'div' : div})


def profile(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("main:home"))


def registration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            formObj = form.cleaned_data
            username = formObj["username"]
            name = formObj["name"]
            email = formObj["email"]
            password = formObj["password"]
            if not (User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() or User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()):
                User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
                user = authenticate(username=username, name=name, password=password)
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'visit/registration/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Below is my views.py to pass that graph:

```
def index(request):
    ### graph plotting stuff ###
    x= [1,3,5,7,9,11,13]
    y= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    title = 'y = f(x)'

    plot = figure(title= title , 
        x_axis_label= 'X-Axis', 
        y_axis_label= 'Y-Axis', 
        plot_width =400,
        plot_height =400)

    plot.line(x, y, legend= 'f(x)', line_width = 2)
    #Store components 

    script, div = components(plot)
    print("@#$!@")
    print(script)
    print("@#$!@")
    print(div)
    # return render(request, 'visit/index.html', context=None)
    return render(request, 'visit/index.html', {'script' : script , 'div' : div})
```

I found this method of plotting graphs [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/bokeh-interactive-visualization-library-use-graph-with-django-template/)
Also If there is an alternate much simpler method to display the graph on django template, please suggest.

I am attaching HTML code in seperate blocks (because its large)

```
<!-- graph bokeh things -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
....
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- graph bokeh things -->


<!-- graph bokeh things -->
  <div >
      {{ div | safe }}
 </div>
  <!-- graph bokeh things -->
```

This is my script part:

```
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
{{ script | safe }}
```

Comment: How it looks your index.html template? Do you have bokeh css and js files loaded in it? Also, "use safe filter if you were not able to see the plot in your template."

Comment: I have edited the content. Do check

Comment: What error you have received? Try to use the console log so that you will come to know where the issue is occurring and even you can check the background log for Django on your terminal. That will help you I guess. Unless we know the error we cannot predict what might be the issue.

Comment: i think this is the error "TypeError: Bokeh.safely is not a function".